# Golang array with forEach to fill model

Tags: go

I have a dynamic import where people can choose what field to use for a specific row.
In Golang, I receive this array obviously and want to loop through the imported CSV and add each row to a specific part of the model. See my current code below.

```
applicant := models.Applicant{
    Prefix:                        "",
    FirstName:                     "",
    LastName:                      "",
    Email:                         "",
    Telephone:                     "",
    Mobile:                        "",
    Gender:                        "",
    CreatedAt:                     time.Time{},
    UpdatedAt:                     nil,
    DeletedAt:                     nil,
}

row := 0
splitted := strings.Split(details[0], ",")
data := strings.Split(rec[0], ";")

for i := range splitted {
    if splitted[i] != "" {    
        applicant[splitted[i]] = data[row]
    }

    row++
}
```

Obviously this won't work because I cannot say (in my for loop):

```
applicant[splitted[i]] = data[row]
```

Because a model does not support indexing. I have been Googling for hours but I am unable to find a solution to my problem.

Can anyone please help me out and tell me how I can make this work?

Comment: `applicant[splitted[i]] = data[row]` When you will have to set the `time.Time` properties, that naive logic will fail hard. Consider the data types you are dealing with. That being said, i d say this is dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926303/iterate-through-the-fields-of-a-struct-in-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that model is an arbitrary structure, you might need to use reflection on order to modify one of its fields.

See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546408/6309), which adds a `SetStringField2()` method, using a [`Value.SetString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.SetString) call to modify the (string) value of a field.

[Example](https://go.dev/play/p/R84relUPWng):

```golang
    a := struct {
        Name string
    }{}

    // works
    reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString("Hello")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
```

Comment: Ohhhh that is so sweet, I will give that a try thank you very much! (will edit main post if I get it working)